# How to know in which partition my application has been installed?

Tags: disk-usage, directory-structure

If I run `df -h` in an Oracle LINUX 5 server, I got below output:

```
 $ df -h
        Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
        /dev/sda2              12G  8.8G  1.8G  84% /
        /dev/sda4             3.8G  592M  3.0G  17% /home
        /dev/sda1              99M   70M   24M  75% /boot
        tmpfs                 942M     0  942M   0% /dev/shm
        /dev/sdc1              51G  1.8G   46G   4% /u000
```

I installed MySQL 5.1.73-community-log in this server which is running. If I run below command:

```
mysql> show variables like '%dir%';

+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                      |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                                 | /                          |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF                        |
| character_sets_dir                      | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                                 | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir                    |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./                         |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90                         |
| plugin_dir                              | /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin    |
| slave_load_tmpdir                       | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                                  | /tmp                       |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please advice about:

- how can I Know in which partition, MySQL has been installed?
- Which Partition will be used by MysQL to store data?
- What is `/dev/sdc1` and how can I use the enough space available (46G)?
- What is `tmpfs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - What is `tmpfs`?

Tmpfs is a file system which keeps all files in virtual memory.
 [Read More](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)

---

> - What is `/dev/sdc1` and how can I use the enough space available (46G)

`/dev/sdc1` is just another file system that you have created and mounted in your system. The mount point is `/u000`. [Read more on mount points](http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html)

---

> - how can I Know in which partition, MySQL has been installed?
> - Which Partition will be used by MysQL to store data?

[Check answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968287/how-to-find-the-mysql-data-directory-from-command-line-in-windows)

> Quoting from answer in the link above:
>
> `mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'`
>
> `basedir` gives the installation directory.
>
> `datadir` gives the directory where the data is stored.

[Refer here for a detailed explanation of each dir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-server.html)

> --basedir=path
>
> The path to the MySQL installation directory.
>
> --datadir=path
>
> The path to the MySQL data directory.

To check which filesystem (mount point) a directory belongs to:

For eg, if I want to find out which file system the `/home` directory belongs to, `df /home`

output:

```
/home                (/dev/sda4     ):  5895840 blocks     92467 i-nodes
```

where `/dev/sda4` is the file system where the `/home` resides

[Refer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/442218/remounting-mysql-under-a-new-mount-point) to change the mount point of MySQL.

Comment: I have already installed MySQL. As per the df command - my installation is in `/dev/sda2`. But, available space is less than 2GB. Now, is there any way through I can move my datadir to `/dev/sdc1`?

Comment: Is there any command to know the total Disk space in my server?

Comment: Yes, I ran `df - H` command and as per the result, it is 71GB only. So, how much the real Hard disk my server has?

Comment: @ursitesion `fdisk -l | grep Disk` shows the total space of each hard disk in the system

Comment: `Disk /dev/sda: 21.4 GB, 21474836480 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 21.4 GB, 21474836480 bytes
Disk /dev/sdc: 54.7 GB, 54760833024 bytes`

Comment: i.e. total 97.5 GB

Comment: @ursitesion yes thats what it means

Answer (score 2):

1. Since your plugin_dir is on `/` ( `/usr/lib64/...` your installation is almost sure on `/dev/sda2`
2. Also `/dev/sda2` as that is where the data directory (`/var/...`) is located.
3. `/dev/sdc1` is a partition on  a different drive, you could configure MySQL with a datadir of `/u000/mysql` after creating that directory
4. tmpfs is a temporary filesystem, i.e. one that doesn't survive a reboot. It has nothing to do with the MySQL setup.

Comment: For #3, can I do this now?

Comment: @ursitesion If you don't have any data in your databases, you should be able to change things. Always stop the server while doing these kind of changes. If you do have data, or want to be safe, then you should stop your MySQL server, copy all the files from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/u000/mysql` and restart the service.